# HTML CSS table row height control

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with two rows of which I would like to shrink the upper one (highlighted in blue) to the height of its child div (`.black`), but I couldn't control the height.

I have tried modifying

- the div's margin
- the row's margin, padding and height
- table's `table-layout` style attribute

but none of these brought me any further.

[image: hello]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEjzxx) with full source code.

The table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px;">
      <div class="col1"></div>
    </td>
    <td style="height: 1px;">
      <div class="black"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="out"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The div's style:

```
div.black {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried display: block; instead of inline-block for your cp2 div ?

Comment: @Marc-EmmanuelRamage Thanks, yeah that was the problem, but I thought I would need it for the margin.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of this  `<td style="height: 1px;">` put `<td style="font-size: 10px;">`, and you may have to also add `line-height: 0px`.

Comment: Please note it your row height not individual cell height. you can put the font size in <TR> tag as well.

Comment: Thanks, so on an inline (or inline-block), the height is the line height? Learned something new... :)